# how to post request message pack with okhttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

I'd like to set MIME type to "application/x-msgpack" but the type of MultipartBody should be MediaType so the app crashs.

How do I make a request?

```
val media = "multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull()
val boundary = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
val file = MoshiPack().jsonToMsgpack("sample_file").readByteArray()

val requestBody: RequestBody = MultipartBody.Builder(boundary).setType("application/x-msgpack".toMediaTypeOrNull()!!)
        .addFormDataPart("file", "fileName", file.toRequestBody(media, 0, file.size))
        .build()

val request =  Request.Builder()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8;multipart/form-data")
                .url(requestUrl)
                .post(paramData)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build()

okHttpClient.newCall(request)
```

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.6.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call post once per request you are building.  Leave out the header("Content-Type", ...) call as it conflicts as well.

See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostMultipart.java

So something like

```
var requestBody: RequestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
  .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart(
    "file", "fileName",
    file.toRequestBody("application/x-msgpack".toMediaType())
  )
  .build()

var request: Request = Request.Builder()
  .header("Authorization", "Client-ID XXXX")
  .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image")
  .post(requestBody)
  .build()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will remove `header("Content-Type")`. Where should I write "application/x-msgpack" for the MIME type of message pack?

Comment: You'll have to complete this yourself, use the guide and the above as an example.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I solved it!